# ionic 3 angular making sortableJs working using systemjs.config.js script

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, systemjs, sortablejs

i am following https://github.com/SortableJS/angular-sortablejs and the systemjs.config.js is where I am stuck. I have a ionic 3 angular 4 app.

I created a script named systemjs.config.js in my assets/js/ and then included it in my index.html as last line in the head section as

```
<script src="assets/js/systemjs.config.js"></script>
```

However, doing that it complains it could not find System. Which is the last line in the script
    System.config(config);

if i ignore above step then i end up can't bind sortablejs property error. my .ts and .html  looks like below:

```
 <h2>Drag / drop the item</h2>
      <div [sortablejs]="items">
        <div *ngFor="let item of items">{{ item }}</div>
      </div>

      <hr>

      <h2>See the result</h2>
      <div>
        <div *ngFor="let item of items">{{ item }}</div>
      </div>
```

.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'dynamic-home',
  templateUrl: 'dynamic-home.html'
})
export class DynamicHomeComponent implements AfterViewInit{
  items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { SortablejsModule } from 'angular-sortablejs'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
SortablejsModule
]
```

**dyamicHome.ts**

```
import { sortablejs } from 'sortablejs'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont know what was the issue here so i ended up using something else called dragula https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula

this worked like a charm